# How can I register a custom Principal type in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, claims

I have an application that is written using C# on the top of the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.

Instead of using the built-in `ClaimsPrincipal` implementation of the `IPrincipal` interface, I want to used `MyOwnClaimsPrincipal` implementation. My `MyOwnClaimsPrincipal` class implements the `IPrincipal` interface.

In other words, I want to be able to access `MyOwnClaimsPrincipal` instance from inside of `AuthorizeAttribute` class or as the `User` Property in the controller and the views.

here is an example of what I want to be able to do

```
public class TestAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // This does not work
        MyOwnClaimsPrincipal user1 = filterContext.HttpContext.User as MyOwnClaimsPrincipal;

        // Yet, this works which tells me that my mplementation is not being used
        ClaimsPrincipal user2 = filterContext.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

    }
}
```

I tried to utilize `Application_BeginRequest` method in the `Global.asax.cs` to set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` at the begining of each request like so

```
public void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var user = new MyOwnClaimsPrincipal();//...

    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
    HttpContext.Current.User = user;
}
```

Unfortunately, that did not work. The `filterContext.HttpContext.User` is still set to `ClaimsPrincipal` and when I cast it as `MyOwnClaimsPrincipal` a null is returned.

How can I correctly set my one implementation of the `IPrincipal` to be used in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think you are to late</strike> <sub>according to [this article](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2008/03/methods-in-globalasax.html) `Application_BeginRequest` is the first event.</sub>

Just guessing: It seems the default authentification mechanism isn't checking if already an `IPrincipal` is assigned, so it overrides yours.

I have done the same using the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` Handler and it works fine:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "42");
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Hello World"));
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MylAuthentificationSheme");
    Context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
}
```

Comment: Indeed `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` sets to set it! However, `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` seems to be called at least twice on each request. I put a breakpoint into the method and it gets called two time on each request. This is expected behavior?

Comment: Probably some second ajax request or an other one? @Junior